# Is there a way to convert the LocalProfileLoadTimeHigh & LocalProfileLoadTimeLow Registry values?

Tags: windows, datetime, registry, converters

For each profile on a Windows 10 box, there's a Registry entry called:
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList{SID}

These have, among others, the properties LocalProfileLoadTimeHigh and LocalProfileLoadTimeLow, with values of 30904031 and 3561385903 respectively.

Does anyone know in what format these numbers are, and how to convert them to actual dates?

Comment: Without knowing, I'd assume these are NT FILETIME offsets, you should be able to convert them to a meaningful duration with PowerShell: `[timespan]::FromTicks(30904031)`

Comment: Thanks.
TimeSpan.FromTicks(30904031) = 3 seconds
TimeSpan.FromTicks(3561385903) = 56 seconds

I'm not sure what that actually means in terms of local profile load time. Maybe it means how long the profile actually took to load rather than the time it loaded?

Comment: Low and High suggests that they are the lower and upper 32 bits of a 64-bit FILETIME.

Comment: Thank you so much. You are correct. Turns out this is a fairly simple conversion!

                                System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ft = new System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME();
                                ft.dwLowDateTime = localProfileLoadTimeLow;
                                ft.dwHighDateTime = localProfileLoadTimeHigh;
                                long hFT2 = (((long)ft.dwHighDateTime) << 32) + ft.dwLowDateTime;
                                DateTime lastLoaded = DateTime.FromFileTime(hFT2);

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the last logon or logoff time perform the following:

1. Open Registry Editor and browse to the below path:
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList<User Sid>
2. Copy the hex values from these two registry values
   LocalProfileUnloadTimeHigh
   LocalProfileUnloadTimeLow
   § Example:
   LocalProfileUnloadTimeHigh = 1d58b41
   LocalProfileUnloadTimeLow = dc0e4c91
3. Covert the Hex Value into Decimal :
   Combine the two values into a single hex value. In this example 1d58b41 & dc0e4c91 ends up as 1d58b41dc0e4c91
   b. Convert 1d58b41dc0e4c91 to decimal (use BING\Google search) In our example 1d58b41dc0e4c91 converted to Decimal = 132164879058357393
   § Run the Command : w32tm /ntte <Converted Decimal Value)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

With the following Powershell code you'll get a PSObject with the username, SID, profile load time and profile unload time:

```
$profilelist = Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"

foreach ($p in $profilelist) {
    try {
        $objUser = (New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($p.PSChildName)).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).value
    } catch {
        $objUser = "[UNKNOWN]"
    }

    Remove-Variable -Force LTH,LTL,UTH,UTL -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $LTH = '{0:X8}' -f (Get-ItemProperty -Path $p.PSPath -Name LocalProfileLoadTimeHigh -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).LocalProfileLoadTimeHigh
    $LTL = '{0:X8}' -f (Get-ItemProperty -Path $p.PSPath -Name LocalProfileLoadTimeLow -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).LocalProfileLoadTimeLow
    $UTH = '{0:X8}' -f (Get-ItemProperty -Path $p.PSPath -Name LocalProfileUnloadTimeHigh -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).LocalProfileUnloadTimeHigh
    $UTL = '{0:X8}' -f (Get-ItemProperty -Path $p.PSPath -Name LocalProfileUnloadTimeLow -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).LocalProfileUnloadTimeLow

    $LoadTime = if ($LTH -and $LTL) {
        [datetime]::FromFileTime("0x$LTH$LTL")
    } else {
        $null
    }
    $UnloadTime = if ($UTH -and $UTL) {
        [datetime]::FromFileTime("0x$UTH$UTL")
    } else {
        $null
    }
    [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
        User = $objUser
        SID = $p.PSChildName
        Loadtime = $LoadTime
        UnloadTime = $UnloadTime
    }
}
```